# Low Traffic Website - Slow Initial Load

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, hosting

I have a problem with my website and I think it's related to IIS recycling the app pool or shutting down the app after 20 mins of inactivity. As it is a low traffic site, when I first browse to the site the initial load can take up to 30 seconds, then after that it is very fast. If i then come back to the site say a few hours later I get the slow load time again. I'm sure it's something to do with the app pool shutting down after 20 mins of inactivity?

Another problem is that I am hosting via a hosting company so have no direct access to manipulate IIS at all. Does anyone know how I can keep my app alive so I don't suffer from the initial slow load speed issues?

Comment: You can enable caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup a service to issue a request every few minutes to your site which can double as monitoring your site to ensure it's still running. You probably don't have access to the application pool configuration I assume.

Comment: That was actually my idea Josh. Problem is that I have nowhere to run the service that issues the request from. Normally I could do this in windows scheduler but as I'm using the hosting company I have no access to Windows or any scheduled tasks.

Comment: There are some free monitoring services which can probally do this for you

Comment: Managed to find a free monitoring service that seems to be working for what I need. Many thanks!

Comment: @RichieRoo that's awsome!